# Improve/remove the First Posts review guidance text about (voting to) delete

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-delete

When reviewing First Posts, the guidance text is slightly off when reviewing answers; one of the bullet points is

> - Delete *questions* that are noise or are of extremely poor quality

[image]

The text is already customized for post type (questions have an additional entry "Close questions that should not be answered here"), so it can be removed, changed to 'Delete answers' or even 'Delete posts' if you want to keep it consistent with the text for questions.

Actually, I'm not sure it's really useful for questions either. Yes, ♦ moderators can delete arbitrary questions from the First Posts, but regular users would only be able to vote to delete if

1. they cast the final close vote while reviewing (closed questions are already removed from the queue)
2. the post has a score of -3 or lower
3. they have the [20k reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) necessary to delete questions immediately after closure